# A way to silence "warning: Object#type is deprecated; use Object#class"

Tags: ruby, activeresource, activemodel

I have an application that interacts with ActiveResource from a system I have no control of.

It happens that the system sends me a JSON feed and one of the fields is called "type" and, everytime this model is serialized, I get this nasty exception. Since this is a CLI application, it's **very** annoying.

Is there a way to silence this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's one way to silence warnings](http://www.caliban.org/ruby/rubyguide.shtml#warnings) in certain parts of code:

```
def silently(&block)
  warn_level = $VERBOSE
  $VERBOSE = nil
  begin
    result = block.call
  ensure
    $VERBOSE = warn_level
  end
  result
end

silently do
  #do your thing
end
```

Comment: Should returning the $VERBOSE level to before be done in an `ensure` block?